# How to find out browser back button click using gwt history

Tags: gwt, browser-history, gwt-history

I m using history listener for forward and back browser button.But i m not able to find out history back button click.If any idea plz rply..urgent for me...Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can use the tokens sent by History management system to determine what kind of action you want to take. Suppose you are at page1 and that page is identified by the token 'page1'. Now, you move to page2. If you click the back button, you will receive the token 'page1'. You can use this to set the state related to page1. See this [Google doc](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for answer...I just want when click browser back button than find out the browser button click...bcoz on the basis of click event i just perform some code...is it possible to find out the browser button is click....

Comment: No it is not possible. This question is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693527/how-do-i-determine-whether-i-am-going-forward-or-backward-through-my-history?rq=1)