# GWT: onBack and onForward "history handlers"

Tags: html, gwt, browser, event-handling, html5-history

Does GWT provide any way to define click handlers for when the user clicks the back/forward browser buttons? If so, how could I define such handlers? If not, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You cannot do that with GWT. However, you may use the History Token to manage the URL changes

Comment: Thanks @dhamibirendra (+1) - is it possible to do in JSNI/pure JavaScript? Why isn't it possible to do in GWT (and do you have any links to GWT docs that confirms this)? Thanks again!

Comment: search and found an older SO question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693527/how-do-i-determine-whether-i-am-going-forward-or-backward-through-my-history?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

take a look here  [GWT MVP](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html)
they explain very well how to implement a such behavior ( using History tokens). hope it helps.